# using nested async.forEachSeries and async.waterfall to control sequencing of Lambda Node.js code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a portion of an Alexa skill running in Lambda that sends a text to a player. I'm using async.waterfall to control the sequence of calling out to a dynamodb table to get the right ARN for that player (where to send the text to), and then after to publish the SMS via AWS SNS. If there is only 1 player in playersToReceive[], it works. However I need it to work for multiple players. To do that, I nested the async.waterfall inside async.forEachSeries (also tried forEach), but I have the callback structure wrong. I think I need to apply the logic of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308573/questions-about-async-waterfall-in-node-js), but I'm new to much of this and struggling.

```
        async.forEachSeries(    playersToReceive, // array of items             
            function(receivingPlayer, callback){                
                async.waterfall([                   
                    function (callback) {
                        session.attributes.phoneKey = receivingPlayer;
                        callback(null);
                    },                      
                    function (callback) {                   
                        playerStorage.loadPlayer(session, function (newLoadedPlayer) {
                            if (newLoadedPlayer == 'playerNotFound' || newLoadedPlayer == 'errorLoadingPlayer') {
                                problems = true; // set problems flag for later
                                callback(null);
                            } else {
                                var ARNtoSend = newLoadedPlayer.data.TopicARN.S;
                                callback(null, ARNtoSend);
                            };
                        })
                    },                              
                    function (ARNtoSend, callback) {
                        playerSMS.publishSMS(ARNtoSend, textToSend, function (success) {
                            if (success == false) {problems = true}; // set problems flag for later
                            callback(null);
                        })                                                      
                    }                                                       
                ], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, "SMS text had a problem sending.");
                    if (!err) console.log(null, "SMS text was successfully sent.");
                });                                                                                 
                callback();
            },          
            function(err){
                // All tasks are now complete               
                speechText = 'OK, text sent.';
                if (problems == true) {
                    speechText += ' . But there was a problem sending it to some players.'
                }
                response.tell(speechText);                                                                                                                      
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the outer callback needs to go inside the closing function of waterfall. With that change made it works:

```
            async.forEachSeries(    playersToReceive, // array of items 

            function(receivingPlayer, callback){

                async.waterfall([

                    function (callback) {
                        session.attributes.phoneKey = receivingPlayer;
                        callback(null);
                    },

                    function (callback) {                   
                        playerStorage.loadPlayer(session, function (newLoadedPlayer) {
                            if (newLoadedPlayer == 'playerNotFound' || newLoadedPlayer == 'errorLoadingPlayer') {
                                problems = true; // set problems flag for later
                                callback(null);
                            } else {
                                var ARNtoSend = newLoadedPlayer.data.TopicARN.S;
                                callback(null, ARNtoSend);
                            };
                        })
                    },

                    function (ARNtoSend, callback) {
                        playerSMS.publishSMS(ARNtoSend, textToSend, function (success) {
                            if (success == false) {problems = true}; // set problems flag for later
                            callback(null);
                        })                                                      
                    }       


                ], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, "SMS text had a problem sending.");
                    if (!err) console.log(null, "SMS text was successfully sent.");
                    callback();
                });                     

            },          

            function(err){
                // All tasks are now complete               
                speechText = 'OK, text sent.';
                if (problems == true) {
                    speechText += ' . But there was a problem sending it to some players.'
                }
                response.tell(speechText);                                                                                                                      
            }
        );
```